# Android: Can a regular Bluetooth device communicate with BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have tried looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html and searching google but I am unable to figure out the following:

If I am using a regular Bluetooth capable Android device, can I communicate with a BLE device? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the Android device. [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) is a protocol defined within [Bluetooth 4.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications). If you mean by "regular Bluetooth capable Android device" a Bluetooth version prior to 4.0, then it is not possible to connect. But there are Android devices shipping with BT 4.0. Those will work.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth Low Energy is nearly a completely different thing than regular Bluetooth except for the branding.  However, a lot of Bluetooth 4.0 devices support both regular Bluetooth and also LE.  The only ones I've seen that don't support both are little devices that rely on low power usage.

Any cell phone with Bluetooth 4.0 will also support regular Bluetooth.