# How to use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) in an android chat application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am presently working with a chat application where I'm suppose to use Bluetooth LE Technology in my chat application.
Through my research & study over it,i have gone through several links:

1. [Android Bluetooth LE Chat example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489386/android-bluetooth-le-chat-example)

   From here i got to know that serial data transfer over Bluetooth low
   energy is not supported as of then(10.10.14).
2. https://github.com/onlyinamerica/blemeshchat

   The above project i have found bit similar as of my purpose but later on it was in vain.
3. Even gone through several Bluetooth chat tutorials and got to know that the user has to pair their device for their purpose.
   Gone through the following tutorials:

   - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat
   - http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/
   - http://www.pubnub.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-build-android-group-chat-application/
   - http://myapptemplates.com/simple-android-chat-app-parse-integration-tutorial/

I have done loads of research on how to use BLE Technology for chatting but didn't find a good resource on how to implement it.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Can we make a chat application using Bluetooth Low Energy similarly as of Bluetooth? Please give a verified reasons but not opinion based.
2. Can BLE chat application can chat with normal bluetooth application? Give reasons?
3. If possible please provide me some good resource for implementing chat with BLE Technology.

Comment: Here are some links that may give you starting point : a) [BLEMeshChat](https://github.com/onlyinamerica/blemeshchat). b)[serial data transfer over Bluetooth low energy is not supported as of now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21551136/1920735) . c) [Can a regular Bluetooth device communicate with BLE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21330066/1920735)

Comment: I have already gone through the above links during my study & research.

Answer (score 1):

*Although you have done lots of research but my answers to you are as follows:*
**1**.

> Yes,we can but Bluetooth low energy will work similarly as of normal
>   bluetooth for chat and so there will be no difference between the two
>   as serial data transfer is not properly applicable now for BLE
>   devices.

**2**.

> Yes,it can because Ble is just the hardware ie. Bluetooth v4 while it
>   supports normal bluetooth functions.Chat is possible but chat would be
>   like normal bluetooth chat.They have their own set of APIs for BLE
>   programming. You just need to include their API add-ons into your
>   Android apps to access the BLE features but if you don"t then it acts as normal bluetooth devices.

**3**.

> there is no such good resource available but still you can check out
>   normal bluetooth chat by
>   google:https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat You can
>   use this for normal bluetooth chat and then customize it as per
>   bluetooth low energy libraries for android.

Ble technology is used for ibeacon,smartwatches and others as its connectivity covers longer distance Ble Chat functionality is still a big question for the android developers as google has not provided  sufficient material for it while in iOS they have successfully used AirChat with the help of Bluetooth v4 for Ble kind of chatting.

Comment: how can you say to use google-sample-bluetooth-chat in Ble chat?Can you be more clear.

Comment: I have already stated above that as of now out my research and when i tried to work with a similar situation of yours then what i did used this file for bluetooth chat in Ble devices and then customize it with Api of BLE provided....

Comment: @Choke_de_Code do you any sample chat app using BLE ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it brief:

1. You can. Both interfaces are simply used to transfer data. It is up to you what these data look like.
   For a chat application you might want to implement some sort of chat protocol. You have the choice of writing your own or to use an existing one in . May be XMPP, BLEMeshChat or PubNub. They're all providing detail instroctions for implementation.
2. If you mean by 'normal' other chat applications than your one: In case they're using the same chat protocol then yes. 
   Bluetooth and BLE are just using different protocol stacks for data transmission. In order to use both interfaces, you have to implement both of them in your app.
3. The ones you found are actually quite good. Especially the BLEMeshChat. Furthermore you can look at the following: https://github.com/n8fr8/gilgames and if you worry about an Android device acting as a peripheral
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html

I hope this will help you.

Cheers.